# Intellij Idea only issue w/ Groovy compilation: Getting ClassNode#getTypeClass for java.lang.Object is called before the type class is set

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I have a maven project that uses groovy-eclipse-compiler to compile groovy classes.  This project
runs fine from the command line (via  'mvn test').   But when I try to run 
the test inside of Idea I get a groovy compiler bug giving rise to a stack trace before the test can even be run.

I am attaching a link to the entire project,and I am also going to file a bug with the Intellij guys, but 
I am hoping someone on this site has seen and found a solution for this problem.
If Intellij gets back to me I will post the solution here.

project zip file available here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9940067/groovy.compiler.bug.zip

Anyway, I narrowed the problem down to one class which I can slightly tweak to induce or to hide the bug. 
Here it is:

```
    package com.other

    class FooProperties extends Properties {

      FooProperties(File eCeNSHome) {
        assert eCeNSHome != null
        new File(eCeNSHome, "properties").withInputStream { stream -> load(stream) }
      }

      String getString(String key, String defaultValue = null) {
      }

      /**
       * @param key the property name
       * @return the property integer value if it exists or the defaultValue if not
       */
      int getInt(String key, int defaultValue = 0) {
        try {
          Integer.parseInt(getProperty(key))
        } catch(final NumberFormatException e) {
          return defaultValue
        }
      }
    }
```

If i change getInt method below with somethng like

int getInt(String key, int defaultValue = 0) {
    return 100
  }

Then the Groovy compiler bug goes away.  If I leave the code as in the original above the bug surfaces 
(with the stack trace below.)..   Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

PS:  I tried searching similar bugs and i found a report of a compiler bug that has been fixed, but the characteristics are slightly different than mine.

> http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-629

PPS:  running 'mvn test' does not find any tests. but that's not the issue. with the command line we see that the classes at least compile fine (the groovy compiler bug is not triggered.)

### STACK TRACE

BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit '/home/chris/cybergrid/ecens-perception-engine/src/main/groovy/com/other/FooProperties.groovy' ClassNode#getTypeClass for java.lang.Object is called before the type class is set 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getTypeClass(ClassNode.java:1311)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BytecodeHelper.box(BytecodeHelper.java:559)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.box(OperandStack.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:302)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:661)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeReturn(StatementWriter.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeReturn(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitReturnStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:456)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement.visit(ReturnStatement.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeTryCatchFinally(StatementWriter.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitTryCatchFinally(AsmClassGenerator.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.TryCatchStatement.visit(TryCatchStatement.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:366)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1056)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$13.call(CompilationUnit.java:763)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:957)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:542)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:520)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.main(GroovycRunner.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:75)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe fix is to change groovy version from 1.8.0 to 1.8.3. You can try this on the project zip that i originally uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fix for this, but I did find a work-around.
I have similar code that generates the same exception.
If you change your defaultValue from

```
int defaultValue = 0
```

to

```
def defaultValue = 0
```

the error should go away

It seems to be a problem with primitive types.

You could also try making defaultValue and Integer instead of an int.

Comment: Appreciate your comment !  THe nice people at intelliJ found out that this issue was due to an already fixed Groovy bug.  (THank you Peter Gromov@Intellij for 
your excellent support )...    THe fix is to change groovy version from 1.8.0  to 1.8.3.  You can try this on the project zip that i originally uploaded.  So glad that I am now able to go back to working in Idea (as opposed to the 'other leading brand' which i had to switch to briefly when I ran into this bug.)